# How does Uber achieve this UI in WatchKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, watchkit

[image: Uber screenshot]

How does it superimpose elements (the timer is above the map) ?
To my understanding, you can only use background images on groups, no other kind of custom views...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial guess is that they're using a dynamically-generated image of a map as the background image in the group. The giveaway is that, while `WKInterfaceMap` allows you to add custom annotations, you can't draw custom shapes like the blue route line.

I could be way off.

Comment: Yes and no, it's still handled by the phone and not the watch, in the end it's just loading an image as background and the timer on top

Comment: on the other hand i've heard that the uber app takes ages to laod

Comment: Heard that too. That it's faster just walk to your destination rather than using the watch app

Comment: I'll accept your answer. Thanks for sharing your opinion

Answer (score 1):

The way Uber (and most of the big companies custom's UI) is done is that they're just generating an image in the iOS which is the sent back to the WatchKit extensions and simply displayed as an image.

If you want to create your custom UI with hte current version of the SDK, this is the only way to achieve exactly what you want. You will need some hacks to achieve interactivity but you should be able to do that on your own :)